# Web App crashes when trying to plot a timeline chart in Apexcharts with Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, apexcharts

I have a web application where I am using ApexCharts with Vue 3 to plot some graphics. I didn't have any trouble using the scatter plot, but when I try to plot a timeline like [this example](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/timeline-charts/basic/) of the website, it completely crashes and I don't know why. maybe I am doing something wrong, but I can't see any error. I would appreciate a lot if you can give me some help because it is important!

I attach here the code of the view:

```js
<template>
    <apexchart type="rangeBar" height="350" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexchart>
</template>
<script>
import axios from "../../../services/api.js";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
        chartOptions: {
            chart: {
                type: 'rangeBar'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    horizontal: true,
                }
            },

            fill: {
              type: 'solid'
            },

            xaxis: {
              type: 'datetime'
            },
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: 'Prueba',
            data: [
               {
                  x: 'Code',
                  y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-02').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-04').getTime()
                  ]
                },
                {
                  x: 'Test',
                  y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-04').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-08').getTime()
                  ]
                },
                {
                  x: 'Validation',
                  y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-08').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-12').getTime()
                  ]
                },
                {
                  x: 'Deployment',
                  y: [
                    new Date('2019-03-12').getTime(),
                    new Date('2019-03-18').getTime()
                  ]
                },
            ]
          },
      ], //end series
    }; //end return
  }, //end data

}
</script>
<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong in library

[image: err msg]

If you deep clone series it seems to work

```
<apexchart type="rangeBar" height="350" :options="chartOptions" :series="JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(series))"></apexchart>
```

Comment: I was in agony. You set me free.